# How to optimise QAOA

Tags: quantum-algorithms, vqe, qaoa

I have a similarly naive question about the classical part of the optimisation in the Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm. Specifically, the cost function is given prescribed as

\begin{align}
f_{\rm cost} &= \langle \psi(\beta,\gamma) | H_{\rm target} | \psi(\beta,\gamma) \rangle \\
             &=  \langle \psi(\beta,\gamma) | \prod_{<ij>} e^{J \sigma_i^z \otimes \sigma_j^z} | \psi(\beta,\gamma) \rangle \qquad (1)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
|\psi(\beta,\gamma)\rangle = \prod_{j=1}^M \exp({-i\gamma_jH_{\rm mixer}})\exp({-i\beta_j H_{\rm target})} |0 \rangle.  \qquad (2)
\end{align}

Essentially, one adiabatically evolves the zero state according to Eq. (2) and then measures the observable as described from Eq. (1).

My question is 2-fold:

1. The experimental outcome from Eq. (1) is a statistical average of the value of the observable (e.g. the target energy of the supposedly ground state of $H_{\rm target}$, $|\psi \rangle$), i.e. a number in $\mathbb{R}$. **How does one actually impose the dependence on the variables $\beta,\gamma$ to optimise using a classical optimiser?** See, [for example this nice review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.08448.pdf), describing the above without explicit description on how the dependency of the angles appears in the output of the quantum circuit (around Eq. (21)).
2. This is a even more schematic or naive. Given the fact that the the parameters are linear on multiplying the corresponding Hamiltonians, **why is the optimisation task hard** (referring to a recent paper by [Bittel and Kliesch](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07267.pdf))? It seems to me that for relatively simple cases, one can easily find the optimum by pen and paper.

Comment: A comment on question no. 2: adding a one particle increases number of possible configurations (members of state vector) by 2, this leads to exponential scalling, hence a hard task.